# tensorflow copy variable but not trainable to pretrain next layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I want to implement the autoencoder (to be exact stacked convolutional autoencoder)

here I'd like to pretrain each layer first and then fine-tuning

So I created variables for weight of each layer

ex. W_1 = tf.Variable(initial_value, name,trainable=True etc) for first layer

and I pretrained W_1 of first layer

Then I want to pretrain weight of second layer (W_2)

Here I should use W_1 for calculating input of second layer.

However W_1 is trainable so if I use W_1 directly then tensorflow may train W_1 together.

So I should create W_1_out that keep value of W_1 but not trainable

To be honest I tried to modify code of this site

https://github.com/cmgreen210/TensorFlowDeepAutoencoder/blob/master/code/ae/autoencoder.py

At line 102 it creates variable by following code

```
self[name_w + "_fixed"] = tf.Variable(tf.identity(self[name_w]),
                                            name=name_w + "_fixed",
                                            trainable=False)
```

However it calls error cause it use uninitialized value

How should I do to copy variable but make it not trainable to pretrain next layers??

Comment: See [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326002/tensorflow-get-variable-change-shared-variable-trainable-to-false)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if still relevant, but I'll try anyway.

Generally, what I do in a situation like that is the following:

- Populate the (default) graph according to the model you are building, e.g. for the first training step just create the first convolutional layer `W1` you mention. When you train the first layer you can store the saved model once training is finished, then reload it and add the ops required for the second layer `W2`. Or you can just build the whole graph for `W1` from scratch again directly in the code and then add the ops for `W2`.
- If you are using the restore mechanism provided by Tensorflow, you will have the advantage that the weights for `W1` are already the pre-trained ones. If you don't use the restore mechanism, you will have to set the `W1` weights manually, e.g. by doing something shown in the snippet further below.
- Then when you set up the training op, you can pass a list of variables as `var_list` to the optimizer which explicitly tells the optimizer which parameters are updated in order to minimize the loss. If this is set to `None` (the default), it just uses what it can find in `tf.trainable_variables()` which in turn is a collection of all `tf.Variables` that are trainable. May be check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180888/how-to-use-pre-trained-model-as-non-trainable-sub-network-in-tensorflow), too, which basically says the same thing.
- When using the `var_list` argument, graph collections come in handy. E.g. you could create a separate graph collection for every layer you want to train. The collection would contain the trainable variables for each layer and then you could very easily just retrieve the required collection and pass it as the `var_list` argument (see example below and/or the remark in the above linked documentation).

**How to override the value of a variable:** `name` is the name of the variable to be overriden, `value` is an array of the appropriate size and type and `sess` is the session:

```
variable = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(name)
sess.run(tf.assign(variable, value))
```

Note that the `name` needs an additional `:0` in the end, so e.g. if the weights of your layer are called `'weights1'` the `name` in the example should be `'weights1:0'`.

**To add a tensor to a custom collection**: Use something along the following lines:

```
tf.add_to_collection('layer1_tensors', weights1)
tf.add_to_collection('layer1_tensors', some_other_trainable_variable)
```

Note that the first line creates the collection because it does not yet exist and the second line adds the given tensor to the existing collection.

**How to use the custom collection:** Now you can do something like this:

```
# loss = some tensorflow op computing the loss
var_list = tf.get_collection_ref('layer1_tensors')
optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss=loss, var_list=var_list)
```

You could also use `tf.get_collection('layer_tensors')` which would return you a copy of the collection.

Of course, if you don't wanna do any of this, you could just use `trainable=False` when creating the graph for all variables you don't want to be trainable as you hinted towards in your question. However, I don't like that option too much, because it requires you to pass in booleans into the functions that populate your graph, which is very easily overlooked and thus error-prone. Also, even if you decide to it like that, you would still have to restore the non-trainable variables manually.