# Is it possible to make a trainable variable not trainable?

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I created a ***trainable** variable* in a scope. Later, I entered the same scope, set the scope to `reuse_variables`, and used `get_variable` to retrieve the same variable. However, I cannot set the variable's trainable property to `False`. My `get_variable` line is like:

```
weight_var = tf.get_variable('weights', trainable = False)
```

But the variable `'weights'` is still in the output of `tf.trainable_variables`.

Can I set a shared variable's `trainable` flag to `False` by using `get_variable`?

The reason I want to do this is that I'm trying to reuse the low-level filters pre-trained from VGG net in my model, and I want to build the graph like before, retrieve the weights variable, and assign VGG filter values to the weight variable, and then keep them fixed during the following training step.

Comment: The `var_list` argument in the [`minimize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer) function is the standard place to specify training on only some variables.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After looking at the documentation and the code, I was **not** able to find a way to remove a Variable from the `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`.

#### Here is what happens:

- The first time `tf.get_variable('weights', trainable=True)` is called, the variable is added to the list of `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`.
- The second time you call `tf.get_variable('weights', trainable=False)`, you get the same variable but the argument `trainable=False` has no effect as the variable is already present in the list of `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` (and there is **no way to remove it** from there)

#### First solution

When calling the `minimize` method of the optimizer (see [doc.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Optimizer)), you can pass a `var_list=[...]` as argument with the variables you want to optimizer.

For instance, if you want to freeze all the layers of VGG except the last two, you can pass the weights of the last two layers in `var_list`.

#### Second solution

You can use a `tf.train.Saver()` to save variables and restore them later (see [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables)).

- First you train your entire VGG model with **all trainable** variables. You save them in a checkpoint file by calling `saver.save(sess, "/path/to/dir/model.ckpt")`.
- Then (in another file) you train the second version with **non trainable** variables. You load the variables previously stored with `saver.restore(sess, "/path/to/dir/model.ckpt")`.

Optionally, you can decide to save only some of the variables in your checkpoint file. See the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/state_ops#Saver) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same thing to find if I can remove a variable from the collection of ```TRAINABLE_VARIABLES```, but could not. Looks like define a list of trainable list is the best for me.

Comment: Hold on, I just found that ```get_collection_ref()``` returns a reference of the trainable_variables collection, which I should be able to change and remove some entries. I haven't tested it yet. Anyway that's less important. I can always filter the trainable variables I got from ```get_collection()``` and send it to optimizer.

Comment: Does change trainable collection by `get_collection_ref()` have any side effect?

Comment: @Olivier It is **NOT** true that you cannot remove a trainable variable from the list of trainables. You can do `trainable_collection = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` to get a reference for the collection of trainable variables, which is a python list, and then use `pop` with the right index to remove the variable from there. I tested it and it prevents the variable from being trained.

Comment: I'm adding an answer with the method to remove variables from the TRAINABLE_VARIABLES collection

Comment: remove from trainable_variables:  just mess with `tf.get_default_graph()._collections['trainable_variables']`. btw it's useless by the time apply_gradient() is called

Answer (score 14):

When you want to train or optimize only certain layers of a pre-trained network, this is what you need to know.

TensorFlow's `minimize` method takes an optional argument `var_list`, a list of variables to be adjusted through back-propagation.

If you don't specify `var_list`, any TF variable in the graph could be adjusted by the optimizer. When you specify some variables in `var_list`, TF holds all other variables constant.

Here's an example of a script which [jonbruner](https://www.reddit.com/user/jonbruner) and his collaborator have used.

```
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
g_vars = [var for var in tvars if 'g_' in var.name]
g_trainer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(g_loss, var_list=g_vars)
```

This finds all the variables they defined earlier that have "g_" in the variable name, puts them into a list, and runs the ADAM optimizer on them.

You can find the related answers here on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-only-train-the-final-layer-of-a-Neural-Net-in-TensorFlow-that-was-already-trained)

Comment: Sorry I know this is an old thread but what does g_loss refer to? Trying to replicate your solution

Answer (score 7):

In order to remove a variable from the list of trainable variables, you can first access the collection through:

`trainable_collection = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)`

There, `trainable_collection` contains a reference to the collection of trainable variables. If you pop elements from this list, doing for example `trainable_collection.pop(0)`, you are going to remove the corresponding variable from the trainable variables, and thus this variable will not be trained.

Although this works with `pop`, I am still struggling to find a way to correctly use `remove` with the correct argument, so we don't depend on the index of the variables.

**EDIT:** Given that you have the name of the variables in the graph (you can obtain that by inspecting the graph protobuf or, what is easier, using Tensorboard), you can use it to loop through the list of trainable variables and then remove the variables from the trainable collection.
Example: say that I want the variables with names `"batch_normalization/gamma:0"` and `"batch_normalization/beta:0"` **NOT** to be trained, but they are already added to the `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection. What I can do is:
`

```
#gets a reference to the list containing the trainable variables
trainable_collection = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
variables_to_remove = list()
for vari in trainable_collection:
    #uses the attribute 'name' of the variable
    if vari.name=="batch_normalization/gamma:0" or vari.name=="batch_normalization/beta:0":
        variables_to_remove.append(vari)
for rem in variables_to_remove:
    trainable_collection.remove(rem)
```

`
This will successfully remove the two variables from the collection, and they will not be trained anymore.

Comment: I tried your method, but unfortunately it does NOT work, at least for TF version 1.6.0.   
To be precise, it "wins the battle but loses the war"!  
It indeed nukes the trainable variables from being listed as trainable [as shown by calling `tf.trainable_variables()` ]...  but the `minimize()` method carries on as if nothing had happened - i.e. those variables are still being trained!
My guess is that when minimize() is first called, it takes a "snapshot" of what variables to train, and then it keeps using them regardless of later changes in the graph collection GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES

Comment: Thank you for noting this. I worked always with versions above 1.10. Do you have some code exemplifying this behavior so I can check with later versions and also try to understand why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.get_collection_ref to get the reference of collection rather than tf.get_collection