# How to fine-tune weights in specific layers in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement [Progressive Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04671) and in this paper, the author applied transfer learning to exploit previously learned knowledge to train current reinforcement learning agents. 2 Questions:

1. How can I lock certain layers so that the weights and biases of these layers can't be updated?
2. And how can I only train specific layers during training?

Here is my code:

```python
def __create_network(self):
    with tf.variable_scope('inputs'):
        self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[-1, 80, 80, 4], dtype=tf.float32, name='input_data')

    with tf.variable_scope('networks'):
        with tf.variable_scope('conv_1'):
            self.conv_1 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.inputs, num_outputs=32,
                                      kernel_size=[8, 8], stride=4, padding='SAME')

        with tf.variable_scope('conv_2'):
            self.conv_2 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_1, num_outputs=64,
                                      kernel_size=[4, 4], stride=2, padding='SAME')

        with tf.variable_scope('conv_3'):
            self.conv_3 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_2, num_outputs=64,
                                      kernel_size=[3, 3], stride=1, padding='SAME')

        with tf.variable_scope('fc'):
            self.fc = slim.fully_connected(slim.flatten(self.conv_3), 512, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)
```

I want to lock `conv_1`, `conv_2` and `conv_3` and only train `fc` after restoring checkpoint data.

Answer (score 1):

To lock certain variables it is slightly complicated and there are a few ways to do it. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326002/tensorflow-get-variable-change-shared-variable-trainable-to-false) covers it and is quite similar to your question.

The easy way out would be to do the following:

```py
fc_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='fc')
train_op = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=fc_vars)
```