# How does one set different learning rates for different layers or variables in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I know that one can simply do it for all of them using something as in the tutorials:

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
```

however it would be nice it one could pass a dictionary that maps the variable name to its corresponding learning rate. Is that possible?

I know that one could simply use `compute_gradients()` followed by `apply_gradients()` and do it manually but that seems silly. Is there a smarter way to assign specific learning rates to specific variables?

Is the only way to do this to create specific optimizer as in:

```
# Create an optimizer with the desired parameters.
opt = GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
# Add Ops to the graph to minimize a cost by updating a list of variables.
# "cost" is a Tensor, and the list of variables contains tf.Variable
# objects.
opt_op = opt.minimize(cost, var_list=<list of variables>)
```

and simply give the specific learning rate to each optimizer? But that would mean we have a list of optimizers and hence, we would need to apply the learning rule with sess.run to each optimizer. Right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set layer-wise learning rate in Tensorflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I disagree with @lejlot, you can set different learning rates for example when you finetune the last layer of a network.

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot but lejlot explained how its not (S)GD any more. Isn't he right in that respect? (it might be practical to do it but it has no theoretical backup nor can it be called (S)GD, right?)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell this is not possible. Mostly because this is not really a valid gradient descent then. There are plenty of optimizers which learn on their own variable specific scaling factors (like Adam or AdaGrad). Specyfing per-variable learning rate (constant one) would mean that you do not follow the gradient anymore, and while it makes sense for well formulated mathematically methods, simply setting them to a pre-defined values is just a heuristic, which I believe is a reason for not implementing this in core TF.

As you said - you can always do it on your own, define your own optimizer, iterate over variables between compute gradients and apply them, which would be around 3-4 lines of code (one to compute the gradients, one to iterate and add multiplication ops, and one to apply them back), and as far as I know - this is the simplest solution to achieve your goal.

Comment: interesting, I didn't think that there was a profound reason. Why is it that having different learning rates is not stochastic gradient descent?

Comment: So (S)GD is defined as an operation doing an update of the form: `theta_(i+1)= theta_i - alpha_(i+1) * gradient_(theta)[cost](theta_i)`, where `alpha_i` is a scalar (which can change in every iteration). Adding scaling factors per-dimension makes it no longer use this equation. It is no longer a valid gradient simply scaled by a single value, efficiently you are artificially modifing which dimensions of the gradient you trust and which you do not. While this might work in practise,it simply breaks out of the well defined mathematical scheme which was used to define this optimization technique.

Comment: that makes sense to me. But if one insists on not using BN and ReLu, how is there any hope in training a model that uses any other non-linearity? the vanishing gradient problem only affects lowest layers, so intuitively, It would be nice to give them a higher learning rate (this is just a specific example, there are other scenarios where per variable learning rate is a good idea, but thats not the point of my follow up).

Comment: I am not saying you are not supposed to do that. I am saying you are proposing a specific heuristic, which is not well defined. There are well defined methods of scaling these things - like Adam or AdaGrad, use them

Comment: I understand you are not saying Im not suppose to do it (you recognize its potential practical importance). However, I also prefer to use methods that are well researched or are principled. My question was just out of curiosity, but I agree AdaGrad and Adam are better defined/researched.

Comment: If we have a very big matrix of parameters (which some might be more important than others etc), then AdaGrad and Adam put a specific/special learning rate to each parameter, is that what your saying? (Just trying to understand a better method than using the hack I came up)

Comment: I am saying that both methods (and many others) will go away from simple GD towards adapting a better step sizes for a particular variables using their knowledge of local geometry of the error surface, which will be updated during optimization procedure.