# How to get predictions out of tensorflow model after you've used tf.group on your optimizers

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to write something similar to google's wide and deep learning after running into difficulties of doing multi-class classification(12 classes) with the sklearn api. I've tried to follow the advice in a couple of posts and used the tf.group(logistic_regression_optimizer, deep_model_optimizer). It seems to work but I was trying to figure out how to get predictions out of this model. I'm hoping that with the tf.group operator the model is learning to weight the logistic and deep models differently but I don't know how to get these weights out so I can get the right combination of the two model's predictions. Thanks in advance for any help.

https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/Cs0R75AGi8A

[How to set layer-wise learning rate in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow?newreg=36393d6817284f17a94e89454f0fa079)

Answer (score 0):

`tf.group()` creates a node that forces a list of other nodes to run using control dependencies. It's really just a handy way to package up logic that says "run this set of nodes, and I don't care about their output". In the discussion you point to, it's just a convenient way to create a single `train_op` from a pair of training operators.

If you're interested in the value of a Tensor (e.g., weights), you should pass it to `session.run()` explicitly, either in the same call as the training step, or in a separate session.run() invocation. You can pass a list of values to `session.run()`, for example, your `tf.group()` expression, as well as a Tensor whose value you would like to compute.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks I was running session.run() on my tf.group() expression but I wasn't passing the prediction functions from my deep and logistic models. Unfortunately both of these functions predictions sum to 1. I want the models to have a constraint that the sum of both of their predictions sum to 1.