# Enable and disable learning of a variable during training

Tags: tensorflow

I want to either start or stop the learning of a variable during training. Although `Variable`'s constructor has a `trainable` parameter, this parameter cannot be changed after construction.

To achieve this effect, my current solution is to save the model at the point I want to change the trainable status of a variable, reconstruct the network with the variables set to the desired trainable status, and reload the weights.

Is there a less cumbersome way to change the effect of training on a variable programmatically?

Comment: You can create a new training op that only has the variables that you want to optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TF 1.8 this can now be done easily by setting a custom learning rate multiplier to variables that can be dynamically set to 0 or 1, effectively switching on or off the training of the variable.

More on custom learning rate multipliers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50388264/1735003).