# Freeze parts of neural net in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I have a deep network of fully connected layers created using slim. I would like to do training of the network gradually - first allowing the first layer to be optimized, then the second and so forth. Reading, I see that this might be done using tf.stop_gradient, although how one does this is not clear.
 Perhaps a better way is to use the trainable flag in the slim call - just set all but the first layer to be false. Unfortunately, this would require gradually setting subsequent layers to true as the training progresses, changing the graph. Not sure if this is legal.

My questions:
- are these reasonable approaches for what I want to do?
- can anyone suggests how to implement either approach?

Comment: I had a [more general version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681295/enable-and-disable-learning-of-a-variable-during-training) of this question, with no answer yet. Hopefully the fact that you limit your problem to a progressive, layer-wise learning makes a solution easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common use is something like this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_function)
```

Now, you can provide to `minimize` another parameter that is `var_list`, that is a list of variables you want to change in order to minimize your loss_fuction.

So, you can optimize only a subset of all your variables, that is, freezing all the rest.

Thus, suppose you have a graph an you want to optimize first a layer and then another layer. Then, you can use something like this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op1 = optimizer.minimize(loss_function, var_list=<list of first layer variables>)
train_op2 = optimizer.minimize(loss_function, var_list=<list of second layer variables>)
```

And then, in your running phase, you will run `train_op1` and `train_op2` according to your optimization schedule (e.g. a loop on the first layer and then a loop on the second layer)

(P.S. None prevents you to use two different loss functions for the first layer only and then for both layers. In this case, the optimizer will minimize with respect to only those variables the loss_function depends on.)

*Edit after a while:* In this approach, a possible update scheme could be:

```
while <some condition>:
    sess.run(train_op1)
    sess.run(train_op2)
```

This process will update the variables in the `var_list` of the first operation `train_op1` and then it will use these updated parameters to updated the variables in the `var_list` of the second operation `train_op2`.

However, sometimes you need that both the updates will use the initial values of both the variables to compute the gradients and, only after, updates all variables to the new one. This is usually necessary when you have different loss functions for the two set of variables.In this case, you have to put some dependencies on your graph:

```
grad_var1 = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_function1, var_list=<list of first layer variables>)
grad_var2 = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_function2, var_list=<list of second layer variables>)
with tf.control_dependencies([grad_var1, grad_var2]):
    train_op1 = optimizer.apply_gradients(grad_var1)
    train_op2 = optimizer.apply_gradients(grad_var2)
train_op = tf.group(train_op1, train_op2)
```

Comment: This looks interesting...I will try it asap.