# Multi task learning in tensorflow with different learning rates

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to implement a multi task learning framework in tensorflow. I'm currently implementing something like this (pseudo code)

```
define_reg_cost()
define_clas_cost()

reg_optimizer.(reg_learning_rate).min(reg_cost)
clas_optimizer.(clas_learning_rate).min(clas_cost)

for num_iterations:
    reg_optimizer.run()
    clas_optimizer.run()
```

This dosen't seem the right approach to me.
I have two loss functions and I want to learn the weights to minimize both losses with different learning rates in the same optimizer. 
I basically want the gradient optimizer to do updates like this:

> weight_updated = weight - learning_rate_1 * d(loss1)/dw - learning_rate_2 * d(loss2)/dw

Any tips on how to do this (possibly using optimizer.apply_gradients())?

Comment: You can get rid of the 2 optimizers by reimplementing 'minimize', allowing multiple learning rates. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Late but maybe helpfull for others:
The solution you have shown would be exactly the right one.

If you take a look at: [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-multi-task-learning-3-lessons-learned-7d0193d71fd6) and:
[this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52228323)

> If you were using something like GradientDescentOptimizer, these would
>   be very similar operations. That's because taking gradients is a
>   linear operation, and the gradient of a sum is the same as the sum of
>   the gradients.
>
> But, ADAM does something special: regardless of the scale of your
>   loss, it scales the gradients so that they're always on the order of
>   your learning rate. If you multiplied your loss by 1000, it wouldn't
>   affect ADAM, because the change it would be normalized away.

using two distinct optimisers has a lot of advantages.

You also could split the update in gradient calculation and update and apply the lerningrate directly to the diffrent parts of gradients.
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34951945)