# How can I update weights of a model with two different loss function at the same time on TF2

Tags: python, classification, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x, image-classification

I want to train a classification model with two losses as follows:

```
model.compile(optimizer=adam)

@tf.function
def train(model, inputs_data_1, inputs_data_2, y):
  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    logits1, features1 = model(inputs_data_1)  # logits: output of fully-connected layer
    logits2, features2 = model(inputs_data_2)  # features: output of feature extractor

    loss_fn1 = cross-entropy(y, logits1)
    loss_fn2 = euclidean_dist(features1-features2)

    losses = loss_fn1 + loss_fn2

  optim.apply_gradients(zip(tape.gradient(losses, model.trainable_weights), model.trainable_variables))
```

when I try this, it just stopped without an error.

I didn't change the input data by using tf.split or tf.reshape

how can I compile the model and train with two losses?

Plz, give me some opinions or code implementation to reference this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Check does this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953379/tensorflow-multiple-loss-functions-vs-multiple-training-ops) helps!