# Applying custom learning rates to variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In Tensorflow, after I obtain my loss term, I give it to an optimizer and it adds the necessary differentiation and update terms to the computation graph:

```
global_counter = tf.Variable(0, dtype=DATA_TYPE, trainable=False)
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
    INITIAL_LR,  # Base learning rate.
    global_counter,  # Current index into the dataset.
    DECAY_STEP,  # Decay step.
    DECAY_RATE,  # Decay rate.
    staircase=True)
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(network.finalLoss, global_step=global_counter)
feed_dict = {TRAIN_DATA_TENSOR: samples, TRAIN_LABEL_TENSOR: labels}
results = sess.run([optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I want a small modification to this process. I want to scale the `learning_rate` differently for my every distinct parameter in the network. For example, let `A` and `B` two different trainable parameters in the network and let `dL/dA` and `dL/dB` the partial derivatives of the parameters with respect to the loss. The momentum optimizer updates the variables as:

```
   Ma <- 0.9*Ma + learning_rate*dL/dA
   A <- A - Ma

   Mb <- 0.9*Mb + learning_rate*dL/dB
   B <- B - Mb
```

I want to modify this as:

```
   Ma <- 0.9*Ma + ca*learning_rate*dL/dA
   A <- A - Ma

   Mb <- 0.9*Mb + cb*learning_rate*dL/dB
   B <- B - Mb
```

Where `ca` and `cb` are special learning rate scales for different parameters. As far as I understand, Tensorflow has `compute_gradients` and `apply_gradients` methods we can call for such cases, but the documentation is not very clear about how to use them. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set layer-wise learning rate in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 2):

TO calculate gradient:

```
 self.gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, tf.trainable_variables())
```

Now, you access the gradients using `sess.run([model.gradients], feed_dict)`

Assuming, you have declared the `learning_rate` as a tf.Variable(), you can assign the learning rate using the following code:

```
sess.run(tf.assign(model.lr, args.learning_rate * (args.decay_rate ** epoch)))
```

The above code is just an example. You can modify it to be used for your purpose.

Comment: In that case, I would require to code my own optimizer, instead of using Tensorflow ones. Anyway it looks like the way to go, since it seems there is no other option.

Comment: Are you sure this will work ?? As far as I know, assign takes references means model.lr should be a pointer to the learning rate, whereas learning rate is a float value

Answer (score 1):

Custom learning rate, in **tensorflow** 
are very easy to handle.

learning_rate = tf.Variable(INITIAL_LR,trainable=False,name="lr")

and say l1 and l2 are two different learning rates :

```
l1 = ca * learning_rate
l2 = cb * learning_rate
```

you can do any type of mathematical manipulation with respect to learning rate, and apply it in this manner :

`optimizer=tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(l1,0.9).minimize(network.finalLoss, global_step=global_counter)`

Regarding your problem: what you want is actually different gradient for different layers, say **L1 layer (trainable variables containing Ma)** and  **L2 
(trainable variables containing Mb)**

```
global_counter = tf.Variable(0, dtype=DATA_TYPE, trainable=False)

learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
INITIAL_LR,  # Base learning rate.
global_counter,  # Current index into the dataset.
DECAY_STEP,  # Decay step.
DECAY_RATE,  # Dec
staircase=True)

optimizer1 = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(ca * learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(network.finalLoss, global_step=global_counter , var_list= L1)
optimizer2 = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(cb * learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(network.finalLoss, global_step=global_counter , var_list= L2)
optimizer  = tf.group(optimizer1 , optimizer2)

feed_dict = {TRAIN_DATA_TENSOR: samples, TRAIN_LABEL_TENSOR: labels}
results = sess.run([optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

You can find the optimized version of the above code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow)

Please note if you can designate learning rate via **tf.assign** it returns the reference to the learning rate whereas the optimizer expects a float learning value type which probably will/should throw an error