# Additional optimizer affects regularization loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, slim

I'm working with an existing tensorflow model.

For one part of the network, I want to set a different learning rate as in the remaining network. Let's say `all_variables` are made up of `variables_1` and `variables_2`, then I want to change the learning rate for variables of `variables_2`.

The existing code for settings up optimizer, computing and applying gradients looks basically like this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, all_variables)
grads_updates = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step)
```

I already tried to create a second optimizer following this scheme. However, for debugging, I set both learning rates equal, and the decrease of regularization loss was very dissimilar.

Isn't it possible to create a second optimizer, `optimizer_new`, and apply `apply_gradients` simply on the respective `grads_and_vars` of `variables_1` and `variables_2`? I.e. Instead of having this line

```
grads_updates = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step)
```

one could use

```
grads_updates = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars['variables_1'], global_step)

grads_updates_new = optimizer_new.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars['variables_2'], global_step)
```

and finally, `train_op = tf.group(grads_updates, grads_updates_new)`.

However, the regularization loss behavior is still present.

Comment: To make it apples to apples comparison you also need to provide grad_loss param to the second compute_gradients, which should be a gradient for activation tensor (you can try to find a tensor like that among graph ops and send it to opt1 in the vars list) somewhere in between vars1 and vars2.

Comment: Also, can you compute the grads for all steps and then scale grads for corresponding set of vars before sending them to apply_gradietns?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you completely. Executing compute_gradients(loss, all_variables), extracting then only grads_and_vars which correspond to variables of  variable_2, and then use optimizer_new.apply_gradients on these, leads to the same result

Comment: This is regarding my second comment:
grads = opt.compute_grads(loss, all_vars);
g1, g2 = _split(grads)
g2 = [x*lr2/lr1 for x in g2]
opt.apply_grads(g1+g2)

Comment: I'm struggling with the not supported item assignment when splitting g1,g2.
What do you mean by grad_loss of your first answer?

Comment: This a bit tricky topic to explain. Basically, you can provide ibcoming gradient to chain your gradient ops together. Otherwise both opt will create their own ops for backward path, some of which will duplicate. If you provide a minimal working example I can try to figure that thing out

Comment: ah I see, thank you for your support. A working example is difficult, as the code is a mixture of slim and tf, but I will try and edit the post. One question, when I calculate all gradients, through: grads_and_vars = compute_gradients(loss, all_variables), can I then simply use apply_gradients on my new 'optimizer_new' on grads_and_vars['variable_2'] and respectively the original optimizer on grads_and_vars['variable_1']?

Comment: I would think so. They will rely on same (unless your lr is a variable that is conditioned somehow) learning rate though

Comment: I have edited my question, it would be great if the proposed method worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the cause through a comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow) . In my case, it doesn't make sense to to supply twice "`global_step`" for the global_step argument of `apply_gradients`. As the `learning_rate` and therefore the optimizer arguments depends on `global_step`, the training process, especially regularization loss behaviour, differs. Thanks to [y.selivonchyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867889/y-selivonchyk) for pointing this out.