# Is it possible to calculate two kinds of gradient separately in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

```
w_1   = tf.get_variable("w_1", shape)   
w_2   = tf.get_variable("w_2", shape) 
output = tf.mul(w_1, w_2)
.....
.....
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(alpha).minimize(self.cost)
```

As we know, when we run "optimizer", tensorflow will caculate gradient and update w_1 & w_2.

But what i want to do is, first, I want to **treat w_1 as a constant**, I just want to caculate gradient and update **only w_2**. Second, **treat w_2 as a constant** and caculate gradient and update **only w_1**. I want to **take turns** to do these things.

Actually, I have seen this before: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477889/holding-variables-constant-during-optimizer/34478044#34478044). But I use **BasicLSTMCell** module.  I try this code: `print (tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES))`, it shows there are **four** kinds of parameter in my neural network, **which means besides w_1 and w_2, there are other two parameters in  BasicLSTMCell.** 
So, if I use such as `var_list=[w_1]`, the other two parameters in BasicLSTMCell  can not be optimized, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky, but possible, to do what you want. The trick is to define a `var_list` by *excluding* `w_1` (or `w_2`) from the list when you want to hold it constant. For example, you could use a list comprehension to match variables based on their (unique) names, as follows:

```
w_1 = tf.get_variable("w_1", shape)   
w_2 = tf.get_variable("w_2", shape) 
output = tf.mul(w_1, w_2)

variables_without_w_1 = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name != w_1.name]
variables_without_w_2 = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name != w_2.name]

optimizer_without_w_1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(alpha).minimize(
    self.cost, var_list=variables_without_w_1)
optimizer_without_w_2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(alpha).minimize(
    self.cost, var_list=variables_without_w_2)
```

Comment: There are limitations to this though - for instance if for whatever reason you want to use tf.stop_gradient, it's not possible (to my knowledge) to discriminate which gradients you want to let through.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, even likely, that `BasicLSTMCell` gives you access to its internal collection of `Variables` in some way, which you could pass to `var_list`. But a more general way could also be to get the gradients from the optimizer interface directly:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(alpha)

grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(self.cost)
```

`grads_and_vars` is a list of tuples `(gradient, variable)`. You can filter out the ones you want to keep fixed, and then apply the rest:

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(filtered_grads_and_vars)
```

Comment: Do you know how to access BasicLSTMCell internal collection of Variables?