# Train only some of the variables in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow to do a gradient decent classification.

```
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

here `cost` is the **cost function** that I have used in optimization. 
After launching the Graph in the Session, the Graph can be fed as:

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict)
```

And with this, all the variables in the cost function will be updated in order to minimized the cost.

Here is my question. How can I update only some variables in the cost function when training..? Is there a way to convert created variables into constants or something..?

Comment: If you defined your own cost function, you can hard-write the variables that you want constant, and not update them. I don't know if you see what I mean.

Comment: You can give a list of variables into `GradientDescentOptimizer.minimize()` as `var_list` (also see https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#usage and https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.minimize), does that do what you want?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298326/freeze-some-variables-scopes-in-tensorflow-stop-gradient-vs-passing-variables?rq=1

Comment: @HarryPotfleur: I'm using a network that someone else defined and tuned and I'm going to fine tune it by adding more layers..
@fwalch, 
@jean: I didn't know how to use the `var_list` argument. Thanks for the links..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["freeze" some variables/scopes in tensorflow: stop\_gradient vs passing variables to minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298326/freeze-some-variables-scopes-in-tensorflow-stop-gradient-vs-passing-variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Holding variables constant during optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477889/holding-variables-constant-during-optimizer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several good answers, this subject should already be closed:
 [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298326/freeze-some-variables-scopes-in-tensorflow-stop-gradient-vs-passing-variables?rq=1)
  [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-only-train-the-final-layer-of-a-Neural-Net-in-TensorFlow-that-was-already-trained)

Just to avoid another click for people getting here :

The minimize function of the tensorflow optimizer takes a `var_list` argument for that purpose:

```
first_train_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,
                                     "scope/prefix/for/first/vars")
first_train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost, var_list=first_train_vars)

second_train_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,
                                      "scope/prefix/for/second/vars")                     
second_train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost, var_list=second_train_vars)
```

I took it as is from [mrry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574081/mrry)

To get the list of the names you should use instead of `"scope/prefix/for/second/vars"` you can use :

```
tf.get_default_graph().get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
```