# Tensorflow: optimize over input with gradient descent

Tags: tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow model (a convolutional neural network) which I successfully trained using gradient descent (GD) on some input data.

Now, in a second step, I would like to provide an input image as initialization then and optimize over this input image with fixed network parameters using GD. The loss function will be a different one, but this a detail.

So, my main question is how to tell the gradient descent algorithm to

- stop optimizing the network parameters
- to optimize over the input image

The first can probably done with this
[Holding variables constant during optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477889/holding-variables-constant-during-optimizer)

Do you guys have ideas about the second point?

I guess I can recode the gradient descent algorithm myself using the TF gradient function, but my gut feeling tells me that there should be an easier way, which also allows me to benefit from more complex GD variants (Adam etc.).

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: No, I didn't. I actually coded the SGD algorithms myself.

Answer (score 1):

No need for your SDG own implementation. TensorFlow provides all functions:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# some input
data_pldhr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
img_op = tf.get_variable('input_image', [1, 4, 4, 1], dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
img_assign = img_op.assign(data_pldhr)

# your starting image
start_value = (np.ones((4, 4), dtype=np.float32) + np.eye(4))[None, :, :, None]


# override variable_getter
def nontrainable_getter(getter, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['trainable'] = False
    return getter(*args, **kwargs)


# all variables in this scope are not trainable
with tf.variable_scope('myscope', custom_getter=nontrainable_getter):
    x = tf.layers.dense(img_op, 10)
    y = tf.layers.dense(x, 10)

# the usual stuff
cost_op = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(x, y)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cost_op)

# fire up the training process
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(img_assign, {data_pldhr: start_value})

    print(sess.run(img_op))
    for i in range(10):
        _, c = sess.run([train_op, cost_op])
        print(c)
    print(sess.run(img_op))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. represent an image as `tf.Variable` with `trainable=True`
2. initialise this variable with the starting image (initial guess)
3. recreate the NN graph using TF variables with `trainable=False` and copy the weights from the trained NN graph using `tf.assign`
4. calculate the loss function
5. plug the loss into any TF optimiser algorithm you want

Comment: Thanks. I solved it using my own version of SGD ... and since then switched over to PyTorch.

Comment: Use 'tf.get_variable'!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [ScipyOptimizerInterface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface), which allows to use scipy's minimizer. This supports constrained minimization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a solution to the same problem, but my model is not an easy one as I have an LSTM network with cells created with MultiRNNCell, I don't think it is possible to get the weight and clone the network. Is there any workaround so that I can compute the gradient wrt the input?