# Reporting accuracy and loss issues with MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am performing transfer learning on InceptionV3 for a dataset of 5 types of flowers. All layers are frozen except the output layer. My implementation is heavily based off of the Cifar10 tutorial from Tensorflow and the input dataset is formated in the same way as Cifar10.

I have added a MonitoredTrainingSession (like in the tutorial) to report the accuracy and loss after a certain number of steps. Below is the section of the code for the MonitoredTrainingSession (almost identical to the tutorial):

```
class _LoggerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

    def begin(self):
        self._step = -1
        self._start_time = time.time()
    def before_run(self,run_context):
        self._step+=1
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs([loss,accuracy])

    def after_run(self,run_context,run_values):
        if self._step % LOG_FREQUENCY ==0:
            current_time = time.time()
            duration = current_time - self._start_time
            self._start_time = current_time

            loss_value = run_values.results[0]
            acc = run_values.results[1]

            examples_per_sec = LOG_FREQUENCY/duration
            sec_per_batch = duration / LOG_FREQUENCY

            format_str = ('%s: step %d, loss = %.2f, acc = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f sec/batch)')

            print(format_str %(datetime.now(),self._step,loss_value,acc,
                examples_per_sec,sec_per_batch))
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
if MODE == 'train':

    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR,tf.get_default_graph())
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
            save_checkpoint_secs=70,
            checkpoint_dir=LOGDIR,
            hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=NUM_EPOCHS*NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN),
                    tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss),
                    _LoggerHook()],
            config=config) as mon_sess:
        original_saver.restore(mon_sess,INCEPTION_V3_CHECKPOINT)
        print("Proceeding to training stage")

        while not mon_sess.should_stop():
            mon_sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={training:True})
            print('acc: %f' %mon_sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={training:False}))
            print('loss: %f' %mon_sess.run(loss,feed_dict={training:False}))
```

When the two lines printing the accuracy and loss under `mon_sess.run(train_op...` are removed, the loss and accuracy printed from `after_run`, after it trains for surprisingly only 20 min, report that the model is performing very well on the training set and the loss is decreasing. Even the moving average loss was reporting great results. It eventually approaches greater than 90% accuracy for multiple random batches.

After, the training session was reporting high accuracy for a while,I stopped the training session, restored the model, and ran it on random batches from the same training set. It performed poorly, only achieving between 50% and 85% accuracy. I confirmed it was restored properly because it did perform better than a model with an untrained output layer.

I then went back to training again from the last checkpoint. The accuracy was initially low but after about 10 mini batch runs the accuracy went back above 90%. I then repeated the process but this time added the two lines for evaluating the loss and accuracy after the training operation. Those two evaluations reported that the model was having issues converging and performing poorly. While the evaluations via `before_run` and `after_run,` now only occasionally showed high accuracy and low loss (the results jumped around). But still `after_run` sometimes reported 100% accuracy (the fact that it is no longer consistent I think is because `after_run` is getting called also for `mon_sess.run(accuracy...)` and `mon_sess.run(loss...)`).

Why would the results reported from MonitoredTrainingSession be indicating the model is performing well when it really isn't? Aren't the two operations in `SessionRunArgs` being fed with the same mini batch as `train_op`, indicating model performance on the batch before gradient update?

Here is the code I used for restoring and testing the model(based of the cifar10 tutorial):

```
elif MODE == 'test':
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(LOGDIR)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
                init.run()
                saver = tf.train.Saver()
                print(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
                saver.restore(sess,ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
                global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

                coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
                threads =[]
                try:
                    for qr in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS):
                        threads.extend(qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, daemon=True,start=True))
                    print('model restored')
                    i =0
                    num_iter = 4*NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN/BATCH_SIZE
                    print(num_iter)
                    while not coord.should_stop() and i < num_iter:
                        print("loss: %.2f," %loss.eval(feed_dict={training:False}),end="")
                        print("acc: %.2f" %accuracy.eval(feed_dict={training:False}))
                        i+=1
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    coord.request_stop(e)
                coord.request_stop()
                coord.join(threads,stop_grace_period_secs=10)
```

**Update** :

So I was able to fix the issue. However, i am not sure why it worked. In the `arg_scope` for the inception model i was passing in an `is_training` Boolean placeholder for Batch Norm and dropout used by inception.  However, when I removed the placeholder and  just set the `is_training` keyword to true, the accuracy on the training set when the model was restored was extremely high. This was the same model checkpoint that previously performed poorly. When i trained it i always had the `is_training` placeholder set to true. Having the `is_training` set to true while testing would mean batch Norm is now using th sample mean and variance.

Why would telling Batch Norm to now use the sample average and sample standard deviation like it does during training increase the accuracy?

This would also mean that the dropout layer is dropping units and that the model's accuracy during testing on both the training set and test set is higher with the dropout layer enabled.

**Update 2**
I went through the tensorflow slim inceptionv3 model code that the `arg_scope` in the code above is referencing. I removed the final dropout layer after the Avg pool 8x8 and the accuracy remained at around 99%. However, when I set is_training to False only for the batch norm layers, the accuracy dropped back to around 70%. Here is the arg_scope from `slim\nets\inception_v3.py` and my modification.

```
with variable_scope.variable_scope(
      scope, 'InceptionV3', [inputs, num_classes], reuse=reuse) as scope:
    with arg_scope(
        [layers_lib.batch_norm],is_training=False): #layers_lib.dropout], is_training=is_training):
      net, end_points = inception_v3_base(
          inputs,
          scope=scope,
          min_depth=min_depth,
          depth_multiplier=depth_multiplier)
```

I tried this with both the dropout layer removed and the dropout layer kept with passing in `is_training=True` to the dropout layer.

Comment: Is the `original_saver.restore` line ever removed? It seems like you'd want that only once the first time you start re-training, and thereafter you'd use the checkpoints that `MonitoredTrainingSession` saves.

Comment: I haven't removed that but it is only restoring Inception's parameters, which were all frozen. i don't think I said this well, but when i restored the model, the first time, to test it , i didn't evaluate it through `MonitoredTrainingSession`, but in a part of the code i didn't show, but i will add. i restored the model with a different saver which restored all parameters  including the new output layer from the checkpoint file that the training session left. I then started the `QueueRunners` and checked the accuracy. But yes when i then went back to retraining I left that statement.

Comment: @Allen Lavoie I tried removing the `original_saver.restore` line and it didn't seem to change the results. However, I realized, as I mentioned above, that when I restored the model and set `is_training=True` in the arg_scope of inceptionV3, the models accuracy now matched what `MonitoredTrainingSession` was saying. However, this doesn't seem to make sense how enabling dropout during inference increases the models accuracy significantly...

Comment: Interesting. You're using `tf.contrib.layers.dropout`? It does re-scale during training (so that the expected value is equal during training/inference), although that's not a guarantee that it will work well. Can you isolate the effect to just dropout?

Comment: @Allen Lavoie So the dropout layer I am using is the one that is already in the InceptionV3 model from TF-Slim. I am feeding my output layer with the 'PreLogits` layer. Which the model from TF defines to be a dropout on a 1X1X2048 conv layer. There seems to be two inceptionV3 models for slim.  One is `tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v3.py` which I think is the correct one uses `tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.dropout`. The other from `tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py` uses `tensorflow.slim.dropout`

Comment: But yes, I will try and isolate it to just dropout. It could be the batch norm layer, but I don't know how that would make sense. Also the the accuracy on the test set is extremely high too, above 90% when `is_training=True`

Comment: correction: PreLogits is dropout applied to the outputs of an 8x8 Avg pool

Comment: I have confirmed that it is in fact not the dropout layer causing the issue...it is the batch norm layers.  See update above.

Comment: One thought: are you using the update ops (see the [batch_norm documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm))? If the updated statistics aren't committed to variables, I could see this kind of issue popping up (likely there's a transient component based on the current batch).

Comment: So the model code I am using for InceptionV3 comes installed with tensorflow. So the batch_norm layers are already in the code they provided. I am restoring the last  2016 checkpoint from the inception model  zoo. All variables are frozen except the weight matrix and biases for the conv layer I added at the end to represent my new output layer . Would update ops still pose a problem? Since I'm not training any component of inception. Would update ops still be required when `is_training` is true  but all parameters of all the batch norm layers in inception are frozen?

Comment: It does seem like this could be an unfortunate consequence of freezing the graph and then training with it. Could you alternatively use an un-frozen version, then just specify the variables you want to train (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478044/6824418)?

Comment: Sorry what i meant by frozen was that i was just telling the optimizer to only train the parameters (via `var_list` )of my new conv layer. I did the same as in that post you linked . Not sure if frozen was the correct term.

Comment: @Allen Lavoie please post your comment regarding update ops as an answer and I will accept it. It resolved my issue. I was receiving high accuracy during training due to the fact that the sample mean and variance were used at training time and were never taken into account into the long running statistics when testing; the model only appeared to be performing well. I also received high accuracy when the model was both trained and tested with `is_training=False`. I believe this is because the original long running statistics from the checkpoint were used both for training and testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Summarizing from dylan7's debugging in the question's comments)

Batch norm relies on variables to save the summary statistics it normalizes with. These are only updated when `is_training` is True through an `UPDATE_OPS` collection (see the [batch_norm documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm)). If these update ops don't get run (or the variables are overwritten), there may be transient "reasonable" statistics based on each batch which get lost when `is_training` is False (testing data is not, and should not be, used to inform batch_norm summary statistics).