# Tensorflow - optimizing part of a variable

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

let's say i'm optimizing Ax = b where A is a matrix and x,b are vectors.
my question - is it possible to optimize it only on subset of A? specifically, a patch of A.
in other words, i would like to keep as constant a subset of parameters in A.
is it possible in TensorFlow?

I thought about using tf.silce(), but it creates a new reference of the variable

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood your question (or there's missing context), just define the parts of A you want to optimise over using tf.Variable(), and define the parts you don't using tf.Constant().

Comment: let's say i want to optimize a patch of an 64x64 image (not corner). how should it be done? can i concat constant and variable?

Comment: Yes. Tensorflow will only differentiate the variables in your graph with respect to whatever your loss is. Make a custom 64 by 64 tensor made up of constants and variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`tf.stop_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) or the [`var_list`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer) parameter of your optimizer.

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478044/4554460